# Why is my array of nav menus returning empty?

Tags: menus

I am trying to retrieve of list of available menus but the array is returning empty.

```
function get_menus() {
    $menu_list = [];
    $wcs_menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
    foreach($wcs_menus as $m) {
        $menus_list[$m->slug] = $m->name;
      }
      return $menu_list;
}

$menus = get_menus();
var_dump($menus);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing a "s" in your variable `return $menu_list;`?
Your array is called `$menus_list;`

Comment: Oh wow! I missed that! Thank you! 